# Is there a Paizo official way to improve dispel checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, e6

I'm currently playing a game of Pathfinder E6 (the level cap is 6, and you can buy feats, skills, and gestalt levels with XP once you hit cap), and I'm looking for ways to improve my ability to dispel buffs.  We're at the point where most of our major enemies are buffed to the gills, and the ability to reliably dispel some of those would be nice.  I've found [Dispel Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/kobold-press/general-feats---3rd-party---kobold-press/dispel-mastery), but I'm looking for something from a Paizo-published source, if at all possible.  I'm also open to using magic items, but it'll be hard or impossible to find anything that requires a caster level above 6.

Alternately, are there any other ways to dispel buffs that don't involve Dispel Magic?

Comment: The E6 tickles my fancy. Could you link me more information about it? :)

Comment: I don't actually have a link for my GM's adaptation of E6 to pathfinder, but here's a 3.5 version: http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/E6_(3.5e_Sourcebook)

Comment: This is the core concept for E6: http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?206323-E6-The-Game-Inside-D-amp-D

Comment: There are a few incomplete pathfinder adaptations around. I'm running a game using my own flavour of E6 for pathfinder here http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?343628-Pathfinder-E6-MapTool-Western-Marches-style-looking-for-more-players you can see the rules I'm using at the end of the first and in the second post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Caster Level Buffs:**
Since Dispel Magic is a caster level check, there are a lot of easy ways to increase your modifier.  There are a number of traits that grant a +1 trait bonus to your caster level for certain spells, such as Gifted Adept, Lore Seeker or the more general Strength of the Land.  Certain feats can also help, such as the more resonant form of Allied Spellcaster.

**Magic Items:**
Caster level doesn't actually have much to do with the ability to craft magic items.  In Pathfinder, you can ignore any requirement except for the creation feat by adding 5 to the DC to make the item.  That can still hurt, but there are enough ways to boost your spellcraft skill (such as the Crafter's Fortune spell, the Natural Divination revelation, and the Skill Focus feat) that a sixth level character can craft most items if necessary.  Since Pathfinder E6 doesn't appear to have a centralized rule set (I was only able to find the original version for 3.x in 20 minutes of Google searches), your DM may have closed that opening, but it can't hurt to ask.  The DC for the Orange Prism Ioun Stone will be 22.

**The Laser Cannon Flyswatter:**
The best way to get rid of buffs is not dispel magic, but Anti-Magic Field.  Some of the PFE6 rulesets I found had feats you could buy to replicate more powerful spell effects.  As a 6th level spell, AMF might be on the outside of acceptable, but its equalizing effect is actually well-suited to the variant.  Again, ask your DM.

Comment: Caster level buffs: These all look really good, but I can't find Lore Seeker on the PFSRD.
Magic Items: While it may be possible to make higher level items, we're as much limited by money as anything else.  We rarely have more than a few thousand gp at once, and I don't think we've ever had enough to make something as expensive as the Orange Ioun Stone.
TLCF: The higher level spells that E6 lets you cast are either healing spells like Restoration, or a small number of 4th level spells from your class.  Something as high level as Antimagic Field is out of reach.

Comment: Lore Seeker is from the APG campaign traits, found at http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/advancedNewRules.html#traits  There's also a divine version there if you're not arcane.

Comment: you can use eldritch breach (mythic)

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways. These all grant bonuses in some capacity or another that aid dispel magic:

- [Spellscar Oracle Mystery (Magic Penetration Revelation)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/spellscar) (+2/+4 to Dispel Magic)
- [Pipes of Dissolution](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pipes-of-dissolution) (+2 to Dispel Magic for as long as the performance can be maintained)
- [Runeforged Weapon Enchantment (Miserly/Generous Variant)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/runeforged) (3/day when striking an illusion automaticilly make a dispel attempt)
- [Dispelling/Dispelling Burst Enchantment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/dispelling) (Add weapon's enhancement bonus to dispel checks)
- [Scepter of Heaven](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/scepter-of-heaven) (+2 on dispel checks vs spells with the Evil Descriptor or effects created by evil outsiders)
- [All-Seeing Eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/all-seeing-eye) (+1 on dispel checks vs Divination spells)

Comment: Man, how did I miss all of these?  Awesome group of suggestions.